# How to make new copy a worksheet with Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: excel, perl

Say I have a template.xls with only one sheet

I want to generate a new xls containing many sheets, each sheet is using the sheet in template.xls as the template

It looks to me that [SaveParser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel%3a%3aSaveParser) can only create a new xls with that one sheet it has and modifies it, how can I make new copies the sheet in the new xls?

I tried the following code but with no luck

```
my $parser    = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
my $template  = $parser->Parse('template.xls');

my $workbook  = $template->SaveAs('new.xls');
push @{$workbook->worksheets()}, $workbook->sheets(0);
$workbook->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
if you are on windows you can use ole [How do I use Perl and Excel OLE to copy a worksheet to a new or existing workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629796/how-do-i-use-perl-and-excel-ole-to-copy-a-worksheet-to-a-new-or-existing-workboo)

If not, i did not find a suitable perl solution, except parsing the sheet and creating the same sheet again and again from the parsed data.

If you are familiar with java you could use the apache poi library [Copy Excel Sheet using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992104/copy-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi)